# write a Perl program so that Ctrl-C kills all forks

Tags: perl

I have a program which forks a lot using Parallel::ForkManager. The way it does it is pretty simple:

```
my $pm = new Parallel::ForkManager($NUM_PROCESSES);

my $j = 0;
while ($j < $NUM_PROCESSES) {
    $j++;

    my $pid = $pm->start and next;

    [application code here]

    $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

This works fine, but sometimes after running this, I need to kill it. The behavior when pressing Ctrl-C is strange, I think it might only kill one fork at a time.

Do I need to write my code differently somehow to make Ctrl-C propagate to all forks? Or perhaps use a different command? Or is what I'm looking to do not possible?

Comment: Good question, just to nitpick at the terminology: he behavior of signals among processes _is_ involved but sensible, not "_strange_"

Comment: What's your OS?

Answer (score 2):

As per the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09), when the terminal (tty) receives the `INTR` character (usually Ctrl-C) on input and the terminal's `ISIG` flag is set<sup>[1]</sup>, it sends `SIGINT` signal to all processes in the foreground process group for which the terminal is the controlling terminal.

Demo:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use Parallel::ForkManager qw( );

my $id = 0;
sub _say { say sprintf "[%s %s %s] %s", $id, $$, getpgrp(), "@_"; }

my $n = 4;
my $wait = 5;
my $new_pgrp = $ARGV[0];

my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($n);
for (1..$n) {
   $pm->start() and next;

   $id = $_;
   _say "Child";
   $SIG{INT} = sub { _say "Caught SIGINT in child"; };
   if ($new_pgrp) {
      setpgrp() or die $!;
      _say "Created process group";
   }

   sleep($wait);
   $pm->finish();
}

_say "Parent";
$SIG{INT} = sub { _say "Caught SIGINT in parent"; };
say "Now! (You have $wait seconds to press Ctrl-C)";
sleep($wait);
```

Output:

```
$ perl a.pl 0
[1 16590 16587] Child
[2 16591 16587] Child
[3 16592 16587] Child
[0 16587 16587] Parent
[4 16593 16587] Child
Now! (You have 5 seconds to press Ctrl-C)
^C[4 16593 16587] Caught SIGINT in child
[3 16592 16587] Caught SIGINT in child
[2 16591 16587] Caught SIGINT in child
[0 16587 16587] Caught SIGINT in parent
[1 16590 16587] Caught SIGINT in child
```

If the parent process gets the signal, but not the child processes, then perhaps your children are starting their own process groups.

```
$ perl a.pl 1
[1 16766 16763] Child
[1 16766 16766] Created process group
[2 16767 16763] Child
[2 16767 16767] Created process group
[3 16768 16763] Child
[3 16768 16768] Created process group
[0 16763 16763] Parent
[4 16769 16763] Child
Now! (You have 5 seconds to press Ctrl-C)
[4 16769 16769] Created process group
^C[0 16763 16763] Caught SIGINT in parent
```

---

1. You can observe the terminal's settings for `INTR` and `ISIG` using `stty -a`.

   - `isig` (as opposed to `-isig`) means the `ISIG` flag is set.
   - `intr = ^C` means the `INTR` character is Ctrl-C.

Comment: Well the thing is, it seems like it's going directly to some of the children. I can't prove this, but it's almost like it's going to whatever child happens to be printing on the screen at the moment. Could that be the "foreground process" you're referring to? My children are definitely not starting their own process groups.

Comment: Re "*Could that be the "foreground process" you're referring to?*", I never referred to "foreground process".